# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable and I don't know why

Tags: python

I'm making a program to filter out all numbers that do not end in either 1, 3, 7 or 9.

I have tried comparing it to intigers, but that's probaly even more complicated than what I am currently trying.

```
import time
import math
num = 1
primes = [2, 3, 5]
upto = int(input("how many primes do you want to find?"))
start_time = time.time()
while True:
    num = num + 1
    threetest = 0
    digits = list(map(int, str(num)))
    even = str(digits[0])
    num = 1
    if even(len(str(num))-1) == "1" or even(len(str(num))-1) == "3" or even(len(str(num))-1) == "7" or even(len(str(num))-1) == "9":       #(line 13)
    #...
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\test.py", line 13, in
>   
>       if even(len(str(num))-1) == "1" or even(len(str(num))-1) == "3" or even(len(str(num))-1) == "7" or even(len(str(num))-1) == "9":
>
> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: well, `even` is a `str`, as you explicitly assign it to be, and you are using it like a function... what do you expect it to do..?

Comment: `even(len(str(num))-1)` - > `even[len(str(num)) - 1]`. Same for the rest in that line (and possible others). But I've got a feeling that you'll run into *IndexError*.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 I was expecting that the last "digit" (character) of the even str is check to see if it is either 1, 3, 7 or 9.

Comment: @CristiFati you were completely right, now it says: IndexError: string index out of range

Comment: in line 12 you make even a string. And in the next line you try to use it as a callable function.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I am quite sure that I have not rediffined str previously:

Comment: yes, my bad. You're just calling a _string_.... closing as typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could instead try the following algorithm for each number, without having to convert to string:

```
last_digit = abs(num) % 10

if last_digit in [1, 3, 7, 9]:
    # do your stuff...
```